# How to stop CATransform3DMakeScale animating the scale change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, calayer, scaletransform

I am using `CATransform3DMakeScale` calls during pinch gestures to resize a CALayer but each transform call animates from the original scale to the target scale.

Since I pass values from the pinch gesture scale to the transform call, the gesture scale values update faster than the transform animation causing stuttering.

```
- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        pinchScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
        CALayer *layer = [self layer];

        /* During pinching, this gets called again during the animation 
        of the last transformation */
        layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(pinchScale, pinchScale, 0);
    }
}
```

How can I stop `CATransform3DMakeScale` from animating the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the default `CALayer` animations mechanism add this line

```
layer.actions = @{@"position": [NSNull null],@"frame":[NSNull null],@"bounds":[NSNull null]};
```

below this one `CALayer *layer = [self layer];`

Or you can achieve the same result using this, which is even better because disable the animations only for this change and enable the animations after that as @Duncan says in his comment

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(pinchScale, pinchScale, 0);
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Does this remove all animations mechanisms including adding animations via CABasicAnimation? I need to keep CABasicAnimation functionality.

Comment: Check my updated answer maybe is more appropriated for your problem @Shiri

Comment: Yes, using setDisableActions is a much better way to go. That way you turn off the implicit animation for that one change, and then turn it back on. Your initial answer would block all implicit animation on that layer's frame.

Comment: You are right @DuncanC that is why I added another way to do this, thanks for you clarification